# Guests notifications from Skype

Tags: iphone, skype

Recently, my phone began to constantly send notifications from Skype, as if someone was calling me.

[image]

Moreover, the call lasts less than a second, and if I go to Skype in the "Call list" there will be none. Interestingly, such notifications do not come from the desktop version of Skype, only on the phone.

What could be the problem, and how to get rid of these "Calls"?